# How to sort data in a data frame and then access data in a data frame, by indexing by date?

Tags: r, sorting, csv, dataframe, time-series

I am reading time series data CSV into an R data frame, using the `read.csv` function

I am then converting the date column (column 1) as follows:

```
mydata[,1] <- as.Date(mydata[,1])
```

I want to know how to:

1. Sort the data in the data frame by date (ascending or descending)
2. Once the data is sorted, I would like to use the dates as an index into the data frame, to fetch a row of data (i.e. an observation set for that date. How may I do this?

Comment: These feel like the sorts of things that are covered in the most basic [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) or tutorials (try searching for 'R tutorial'). It's hard to motivate to answer questions when there isn't much evidence of effort on your part to learn. Show us that you've [done your homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) and people will be more willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a time series of numbers indexed by unique dates, `read.zoo` in the zoo package does most of that.  Read the 5 vignettes that comes with it as well as ?read.zoo  and in particular the `zoo-read` vignette.

Answer (score 0):

Try this option to sort:

> data.1 <- as.Date(mydata[,1])
>   mydata[,1] <- data.1[order(data.1)]

I'm looking also a answer for second question!!